# Oracle (Continuous Query Notification) - way to get more data in a CQN notification?

Tags: oracle, query-notifications

We are using oracle CQN for change notifications for specific queries.

This is working fine for all the inserts and updates. The problem is delete, On delete the notification is sent with ROWID amongst other details. We cannot use the ROWID to lookup the row any more because it has been deleted.

Is there a way to get more data in a CQN notification regarding the deleted row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

My understanding is that this service is tailored to allow servers or clients to implement caches.  In which case the cached table or view is supposed to be loaded in memory *including the rowid*, upon a notification, the cache manager having subscribed to the CQN service is supposed to invalidate the rows affected by the rowid list (or fetch it again in advanced).

Real life example.  This can be useful for real time databases like Intelligent Network (i.e. to manage Prepaid Su$bscribers on a telecom network) in which callers need to be put through asap.  The machine in charge of authorizing the calls (the SCP, there are several of them on the whole territory) is usually an in-memory database and the real persistent db lives on another node (the SDP at a central datacenter).  The SDP with its on-disk db receives life-cycle events and balance refils events and notifies the subscribing SCPs.

You might have a different usage model.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, instead of deleting a row, I used a column "Active", instead of deleting a row I changed "Active" from "YES" to "NO".